# Changing existing foreach loop on ConcurrentHashMap to use Lambdas to harness parallel processing

Tags: java, lambda, parallel-processing

I am making a game and have a **ConcurrentHashMap** which contains all the players which are currently logged in. I have a AutoSaver thread which loops through the HashMap and saves all the player 1 by 1. When there are not many players this is fine as it doesn't take too much time to iterate but it can slow down a bit when there are many players logged in. I read using java stream and parallel, we can speed up processing of collections, so I tried changing my existing loop to now use **stream** and **parallel**.

My question is, is my implementation correct? Is there a better way to do it? Is it thread safe now?

Here is the existing implementation

```
for(Player player : ActiveConnections.getAllConnectedPlayers().values(){
    if(player != null)
        saveManager.savePlayer(player, true);
}
```

Here is my implementation using stream and parallel

```
ActiveConnections.getAllConnectedPlayers().values()
    .stream()
    .parallel()
    .filter((x) -> x != null)
    .forEach((x) -> saveManager.savePlayer(x, true));
```

**EDIT**
Here is my save manager implementation

```
public class SaveManager {

    private MySqlManager sqlManager;

    public SaveManager(){
        sqlManager = MySqlManager.getInstance();
    }

    public void savePlayer(Player player, boolean autoSave){
       //Saves the player
    }
```

Again I have just started using lambdas so please let me know if there is something wrong.

Comment: That looks right to me... This question might be better suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), though.

Comment: I had no idea there is anything like code review on stack overflow. :) I will move it if it is required.

Comment: The documentation of `ConcurrentHashMap` clearly states that "[...]Like Hashtable but unlike HashMap, this class does not allow null to be used as a key or value. " -- so why the test for null?

Comment: You are right, no need for null checks. I will remove it. Never read about it. @fge

Comment: What's savePlayer implementation?

Comment: It just saves the details of the player on the database.

Comment: Also, this may not speed up as much as you may think; does your `saveManager` support concurrent calls to `.savePlayer()` for instance?

Comment: @fge I am not sure what you mean by supporting concurrent calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is thread safe if savePlayer is thread save. turning a stream into a parallel one doesn't make it thread safe, it makes the algorithm able to be parallelized.

However, if your savePlayer save stuff in the data base, then there is no way to parallelize the player saving part which is what you would like. Meaning that you'll see no benefit from using a parallel stream because when one thread changes the contents of the DB, two things can happen:

- the second thread that wants to save another player, waits for the first thread to finish. If this is the case, then there is no benefit of using parallel streams because threads still have to wait for each other.
- the second thread attempts to change DB data at the same time has the first thread which may lead to incoherent data on your Database. Assuming your code supports more than one active connection to the database.

In sum, you should use parallel stream when the algorithm you want to execute is parallelizable. Internally, parallelStream() divides the stream into sub-streams, and executes the algorithm for each item on each of the sub-streams (concurrently), in the end the result of each sub-stream is combined using the same algorithm.

An example from the "Java 8 in Action" book:

```
public static long parallelSum(long n){
   return Stream.iterate(1L, i -> i + 1) // generate a stream of long values, starting at 1
                .limit(n) // limit the stream to n items
                .parallel()
                .reduce(0L, Long::sum); // this is what we want to execute concurrently, and in the end the result of each sub-stream will be combined using this sum
}
```

For more information refer to chapter 7 of the book.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the SaveManager class. I am not sure how about how I can end up with coherent data on the database.

Comment: You are deviating from the point. The point is, if the savePlayer is thread safe, then your lambda code is correct and thread safe aswell. DB data coherence can be ensured with atomic transactions, using commit and rollback mechanisms. Data incoherence is a problem if your main thread can change player data at the same time that your AutoSaver thread is saving the players. But I dont know if this can happen, so I assumed it could.

Comment: Yeah this can happen. My main thread can change players's value lets say his position on a game map (if the player is moving). So I think I get your point. Thanks